# Symbol for decimal separator overwriten by `mathastext`

Tags: babel, mathastext, decimal-number

I found out that `mathastext` is interfering with `spanish` options for `babel` package. More precisely, when `mathastext` is loaded, the default  decimal separator in Spanish, which is a comma, is replaced by a point, even when explicitly setting it.

This is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,bold,proportional,lining]{montserrat}
  % Using Montserrat as our default font.
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
  % This makes the math font to be the default text font.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\decimalcomma % Not really needed, since this is the default option

\begin{document}
Estos números son famosos:\\

$\pi = 3.14159\dots$\\

$e = 2.71828\dots$\\

$\varphi = 1.61803\dots$\\

Además,
%
\begin{equation}
    \pi = 3.14\dots = 4 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this:

---

[image]

---

Now, if we remove these lines

```
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
  % This makes the math font to be the default text font.
```

from the example above, then we get this:

---

[image]

---

So, **how can I get the comma as the decimal separator in Spanish when I am using `mathastext`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mathastext` package restores the mathcode of `.` at `\everymath`. Restore it back to what `babel-spanish` expects.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,bold,proportional,lining]{montserrat}
  % Using Montserrat as our default font.
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
  % This makes the math font to be the default text font.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathcode`.="8000 }%
  \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\mathcode`.="8000 }%
}


\begin{document}

Estos números son famosos:

$\pi = 3.14159\dots$

$e = 2.71828\dots$

$\varphi = 1.61803\dots$

Además,
%
\begin{equation}
    \pi = 3.14\dots = 4 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! I'll mark the answer as 'accepted' but, would you mind explaining a little bit the code you added, especially the part of ` `.="8000 `??

Comment: @Vicent The `\decimalcomma` device works by defining `.` as “math active” (you find several instances of the in the site) and giving it a suitable definition. This is achieved by assigning the period the special mathcode `"8000`. But `mathastext` juggles mathcodes over and over, so this assignment is lost. It needs to be done at every formula.

Comment: This answer was accepted, but have a look at this new issue caused by your hack: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657650/strange-issue-with-url . I leave this link here for future reference.