# Strange issue with `\url`

Tags: hyperref, babel, mathastext

I have a problem with `\url`. When I use it, LaTeX (i.e., pdflatex with TeXstudio) won't end compiling.

I have a main document with several included `.tex` files, each of them containing a different chapter. I am using `natbib`, `chapterbib`. Everything seems fine (for instance, in order to get a reference section within each chapter, I know I have to execute `bibtex` on each `.aux` file, etc.) I think the issue is not directly related to this.

You'll find my main file below.

When I stop the process (after a long time waiting), I get this message at TeXstudio:

> File ended while scanning use of @@BOOKMARK. \begin{document}

although I am not sure this error message is significant or not.

Do you see something that may interact with `\url` and cause this error message??

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% PAQUETES AUXILIARES Y GENERALES
% ===============================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

% FORMATO DE PÁGINA
% =================

\RequirePackage[a4paper,
top=1.63cm, bottom=2.64cm, outer=2.64cm,inner=2.64cm, 
headsep=0.63cm,footskip=1.00cm,headheight=0.37cm, 
bindingoffset=0cm
]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\raggedbottom
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{1.0}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.0}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{1.0}
\usepackage{everysel}
\usepackage[bottom,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% TIPOS DE LETRA Y EXPRESIONES MATEMÁTICAS
% ========================================

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,bold,proportional,lining]{montserrat}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\fontfamily{Montserrat-TOsF}\selectfont #1}}
 % VER TAMBIÉN `mathastext` DESPÚES DE TODOS LOS PAQUETES MATEMÁTICOS
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono} % Tipo de letra para texto de ancho fijo (listados, etc.)
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{textfit}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath,mathtools} 
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]   
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\newcommand{\slfrac}[2]{\left.#1\middle/#2\right.}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage{bm} % Necessary for greek bold symbols. Usage: \bm{\mu}
\usepackage{relsize}
  % TO ENLARGE SUMATIONS SIGNS AND OTHER MATHEMATICAL SYMBOLS
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
  % This makes the math font to be the default text font

% ESTRUCTURA DEL DOCUMENTO
% ========================

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % ,notlot,notlof

% APÉNDICES
% ---------

\usepackage{appendix}


% GRÁFICOS Y COLORES
% ==================


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  % PDFTeX driver for graphicx.
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % enables use of MetaPost graphics with pdflatex 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{azulVGB}{rgb}{0,0.33,0.58}%{0,0.33,0.67}
\definecolor{verdeVGB}{rgb}{0,0.58,0.33}%{0,0.67,0.33}
\definecolor{rojoVGB}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.33}%{0.67,0,0.33}
\definecolor{grisVGB}{rgb}{0.33,0.33,0.33}

% ENCABEZADOS Y PIES DE PÁGINA
% ============================

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}  % Limpia todo
\fancyfoot{}  % Limpia todo

\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\color{black} \scriptsize{\textup{\thepage}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\color{black}{\scriptsize{\textsc{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\color{black}{\scriptsize{\textsc{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Por defecto ya es así, pero que quede claro

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}  % Limpia todo
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\color{black} \scriptsize{\textup{\thepage}}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\notheader}[1]{\ifx\label\@gobble\dots\else#1\fi}
\makeatother


% TEOREMAS, DEFINICIONES, ENUMERACIONES, etc.
% ===========================================

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\newtheorem{teor}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}


% TABLAS 
% ======

\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabularx}  % en 'classicthesis-ldpkg' y [Thijs]
\newcolumntype{D}{>{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{I}{>{\raggedright \arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X}    
\usepackage{tabularray} % <----- ¡ NEW !
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

% ALGORITMOS EN PSEUDOCÓDIGO 
% ==========================

\usepackage[english,ruled,vlined,linesnumberedhidden]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand{\mycomments}[1]{\textit{\footnotesize #1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycomments}

\SetKw{KwStep}{step}
\SetKw{KwOR}{or}
\SetKw{KwBreak}{break}
\SetKw{KwStop}{STOP}

% FIGURAS, ELEMENTOS FLOTANTES
% ============================

\RequirePackage[section,below]{placeins}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subfig}  % Soporte para sub-figuras
\usepackage{keyval}  % Necesario para SUBFIG (creo)

% PIES DE FIGURAS, TABLAS, etc.
% =============================

\usepackage{caption} % Para \captionsetup

\captionsetup{width=0.75\textwidth}

\usepackage{comment}

% IDIOMAS (BABEL) 
% ===============

\usepackage[catalan,english,spanish]{babel} % french

%\decimalcomma (NO ES NECESARIO, ya es así por defecto)

% To restore the "." symbol that was changed by `mathastext`:
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathcode`.="8000 }%
    \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\mathcode`.="8000 }%
}%

% Redefinimos la manera de llamar a una 'table' en castellano.
% En lugar de 'cuadro' será "tabla" :
\addto\captionsspanish{\def\tablename{Tabla}}
% Lo mismo para "Índice de cuadros" :
\addto\captionsspanish{\def\listtablename{\'{I}ndice de tablas}}

% Personalización de los apéndices (se podría aprovechar para pasar de
% "apéndice" a "anexo", por ejemplo)  :
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}      % Para el título de cada apéndice
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos} % Para la página que marca el inicio de los apéndices
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}  % Para el índice general

\tolerance=5000 \hyphenpenalty=300 \pretolerance=400
% Para no separar tanto las palabras.

% BIBLIOGRAFÍA 
% ============

\usepackage[sectionbib,round,semicolon,authoryear]{natbib}

\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\providecommand{\urlprefix}{ }

\usepackage{chapterbib}


% HYPERREF Y OTROS ARREGLOS FINALES 
% =================================

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true,
pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false, % en false por usar 'footmisc'
pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1 
\hypersetup{pdfstartpage=1,pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref},%
    colorlinks=true, linkcolor=azulVGB, citecolor=verdeVGB,%
    filecolor=rojoVGB, urlcolor=rojoVGB,%
        pdfpagemode=UseOutlines, pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,%
        pdfhighlight=/N, pageanchor=true,%
        pdftoolbar=true, pdfmenubar=true, pdfstartview=FitH}
    
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% ___________________________________________________________________________


\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\textsc{\roman{page}}}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Anteportada (en blanco intencionadamente)}{anteportada}\thispagestyle{empty}

~ \\

\cleardoublepage

%\pdfbookmark[0]{Título}{titulo}\includepdf{portada.pdf} % <----------

%\include{./legal}


\cleardoublepage%
\pdfbookmark[0]{Índice general}{indice_general}%
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage%
\pdfbookmark[0]{Índice de figuras}{lista_figuras}%
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage%
\pdfbookmark[0]{Índice de tablas}{lista_tablas}%
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\include{./cap_1}
\include{./cap_2}
\include{./cap_3}
\include{./cap_4}
\include{./cap_5}
\include{./cap_6}
\include{./cap_7}


% ___________________________________________________________________________


        
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by @frabjous (see their comment below), the issue seems to be caused by the `\AtBeginDocument` sentence. This was actually a hack to restore back the Spanish symbol for a decimal separator (a comma), which had been overwritten to a dot by the package `mathastext` (see [Symbol for decimal separator overwriten by `mathastext`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657343/symbol-for-decimal-separator-overwriten-by-mathastext)).

This is a MWE, as requested in the comments below.

The example cannot be successfully compiled. However, it does when the sentence `\AtBeginDocument` is removed (but the commas inside numbers become points again).

So, this question is already partially answered, but it would be nice to get a working example involving

- `mathastext`,
- commas as decimal separators, and
- URLs.

Currently, I can only have two of them at the same time.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,bold,proportional,lining]{montserrat}
  % Using Montserrat as our default font.
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
  % This makes the math font to be the default text font.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\decimalcomma % Not really needed, since this is the default option

% Restoring back comma as a decimal separator, which was overwritten by `mathastext`:
\AtBeginDocument{%
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathcode`.="8000 }%
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\mathcode`.="8000 }%
}%

\usepackage[breaklinks=true,
pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false, % en false por usar 'footmisc'
pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Estos números son famosos:

$\pi = 3.14159\dots$

$e = 2.71828\dots$

$\varphi = 1.61803\dots$

Además,
%
\begin{equation}
    \pi = 3.14\dots = 4 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} .
\end{equation}

Y esto es una URL: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Code we cannot use to compile and test with does little good. Please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: hyperref tries to create bookmarks from your headings and if you put something odd in them it can break. Use \texorpdfstring to provide alternative content.

Comment: It actually looks to me like the problem is caused by the `\AtBeginDocument` command being used "To restore the "." symbol that was changed by `mathastext`", which is causing problems if a `\url` has periods in them, which of course all urls do...

Comment: @frabjous You were right. I disabled (i.e., commented) the sentences `\AtBeginDocument` and so on, and now it compiles, and shows URLs. I don't get why. Is an URL a maths element, or does it belong to a maths environment?? Do the dots in an URL have the same code as dots that act as decimal separators?

Comment: @frabjous See my edits, please.

Answer (score 1):

Well hyperref doesn't like this mathcode juggling. You could use the `nopunctuation` option of mathastext. Then it doesn't interfere with the decimalcomma and your hack is not needed.

The breaklinks option does nothing with pdftex, the pdftex option is unneeded, and utf8 is the default since 2018 so I remove this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,bold,proportional,lining]{montserrat}
  % Using Montserrat as our default font.
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes,nopunctuation]{mathastext}
  % This makes the math font to be the default text font.
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\decimalcomma % Not really needed, since this is the default option

\usepackage[
hyperfootnotes=false, % en false por usar 'footmisc'
pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Estos números son famosos:

$\pi = 3.14159\dots$

$e = 2.71828\dots$

$\varphi = 1.61803\dots$

Además,
%
\begin{equation}
    \pi = 3.14\dots = 4 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} .
\end{equation}

Y esto es una URL: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, correct me if I am wrong. The `nopunctuation` option of `mathastext` will leave these symbols `,`, `.`, `:`, `;` unchanged, I mean, USING THE ORIGINAL MATHS FONT, won't it?

Comment: yes I think so (I don't mathastext myself, I prefer to use a dedicated math setup).

Answer (score 1):

You can teach `url` that `.` shouldn't be treated specially.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Using Montserrat as our default font.
\usepackage[defaultfam,light,bold,proportional,lining]{montserrat}
% This makes the math font to be the default text font.
\usepackage[italic,defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

\usepackage[
  breaklinks=true,
  %pdftex, %<--- NO
  hyperfootnotes=false, % en false por usar 'footmisc'
  pdfpagelabels
]{hyperref}

%\decimalcomma % Not really needed, since this is the default option

% Restoring back comma as a decimal separator, which was overwritten by `mathastext`:
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\mathcode`.="8000 }%
  \everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\mathcode`.="8000 }%
  \addto\UrlSpecials{\do\.{\mathchar\es@period@code}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Estos números son famosos:

$\pi = 3.14159\dots$

$e = 2.71828\dots$

$\varphi = 1.61803\dots$

Además,
\begin{equation}
    \pi = 3.14\dots = 4 \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} .
\end{equation}

Y esto es una URL: \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}.

\end{document}
```

[image]